# Quoting columns with spaces in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I migrated a database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

Most column names contain double words, for example:

```
SELECT [Column Name] FROM table;
```

...which does not work in PostgreSQL.

What is the correct syntax for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 30):

In most RDBMSs, double-quotes are what are used to specify an exact spelling of something..  (single quotes being string delimiters).

```
SELECT
  tab."This IS My Column EXACTLY" AS col
FROM "My TabLE Name Contains Spaces Too!" tab
WHERE tab."ANOTHER UGLY COLUMN name" = 'MyFilterString';
```

Notice that capital/lowercase also matters when using double-quotes.  (Postgres lower-cases everything when double-quotes are not used ... Oracle upper-cases everthing, etc..)

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE
```

in postgres, is different from

```
SELECT "COLUMN1" FROM TABLE
```

where as in oracle, is different from

```
SELECT "column1" FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This is also referred to in greater detail in the [lexical structure documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

Answer (score 7):

## Moving to PostgreSQL convention

For more information on this see the post *[How do I adopt the PostgreSQL naming convention in legacy database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202446/2639)*

In PostgreSQL by convention and with good reason, we neither use spaces nor capital letters in our identifiers (columns, tables, schemas, etc). The use of `_` is purely style though.

```
SELECT FORMAT(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I RENAME %I to %I;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  lower(
    -- replace all spaces with _, xX and Xx becomes x_x
    regexp_replace(
      -- First, replace spaces with an _
      replace(column_name, ' ', '_'),
      '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
      '\1_\2',
      'xg'
    )
  )
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name ~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]';
```

From there you can edit the commands to be run, delete the ones you don't want, or run `\gexec` and all the problems go away.